# What is the full formula for calculating a FICO 9 credit score?

Tags: credit-score, credit, calculation, credit-history, fico-score

I'm familiar with the percentage breakdown of how a credit score is calculated.  I'm wondering what is the exact formula is that can be used to come up with a point value based on specific input parameters? I am wondering specifically about the latest method of FICO 9.

Comment: FICO scoring formula held by Fair Isaac is proprietary and they do not share the methodology with anyone other than their select top tier partners and those who pay for the $35k (at last check) price tag for the training. It makes sense because they don't want people gaming the system. But there are a slew of fairly accurate anecdotal evidence that can help you get there, a simple search can lead you to them. Hint: start at myFICO.com forums.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The FICO score is an invention of one company, FICO (formerly called Fair Isaac).  The exact formula is a trade secret that the company does not reveal.  This allows them to maintain a monopoly on FICO scores.  The only way to know what your real FICO score is is to ask that single company what it is.  They will not tell you, or anyone else, how to calculate it yourself, beyond the rough percentage guidelines you mentioned.